# How to select the tag accurately from the tag column with the list of tag?

Tags: php, mysql, tagging, sql-like

How can I select the tag accurately from the tag column with the list of tag?

For instance below is table created using a query, but then I want to narrow down my search,

```
page_id         tags
1               tile-1,tile-12,tile-10
2               tile-1,tile-10
3               tile-12,tile-10
4               tile-15,tile-16
```

the result I am after is the pages with `tile-1` only,

```
page_id         tags
1               tile-1,tile-12,tile-10
2               tile-1,tile-10
```

But the query I am working on below returns all of them, including, `tile-12`, `tile-10`, etc.

```
SELECT*
FROM (...) AS k
WHERE k.tags LIKE '%tile-1%'
```

May I should not use `LIKE`?

Comment: As someone answered below, your schema is really bad. It's totally not normalized. It's better to change it now - if you go further with the project, schema like this will become a pain in the a$$ to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to change schema to page_id, tag. so that your data should look like this

```
1           tile-1
1           tile-12
1           tile-10
2           tile-1
2           tile-10
3           tile-12
3           tile-10
4           tile-15
4           tile-16
```

Then you can do all this with a simple query,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tag = 'title-1';
```

This way you do not have to search through the table (table scans) - which will become an issue once table has more rows (scalable solution).
Second you can use index on the tag column, to make searches super fast.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using comma as the delimiter, your `LIKE`-statement would have to include the comma:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE tags LIKE '%title-1,%';
```

Comment: oh no wait. what happens like `tile-10,tile-1` or `tile-1`?

Comment: Hm, sorry if I misinterpreted your question. If the tags-column only should contain `title-1` then it sounds like you should be using `=` insted of `LIKE`... In the above table you wouldn't get any match, is that what you're after?

Comment: it's ok. I use regex to solve my problem `[[:<:]]tile-1[[:>:]]` :-)